# ViewController add UITableView use scrollViewDidScroll popViewControllerAnimated crash

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Here is all my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pushTableViewController:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;

}
- (void)pushTableViewController:(id)sender {
    TableViewController *tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];

}
```

The `TableViewController` code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIBarButtonItem *myMessageButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(myMessageButtonClicked:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myMessageButton;
    UITableView *scrollTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    scrollTableView.delegate = self;
    scrollTableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollTableView];
}
- (void)myMessageButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

}
```

Just use the most simplest way to use `UITableView`,and implement `scrollViewDidScroll`
when I scroll the `UITableView` to the bottom and then `popViewControllerAnimated` i got crash.
**is this BUG of IOS? or where did i go wrong?**

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: when do you `popViewControllerAnimated`? what does the crash log say?

Comment: When i scroll the 'UITableView' to the bottom then  'popViewControllerAnimated' no crash log just crash.bye the way the code is just the simple use 'UITableView' and 'scrollViewDidScroll',no more code @staticVoidMan

Comment: put break points and check

Comment: this certainly is not a bug in iOS :D...

Comment: hi @rdelmar the 'UITableView' just use normally just implement 'scrollViewDidScroll' use 'pushViewController' to push the 'UITableView' ViewController and scroll to bottom then 'popViewControllerAnimated' crash.

Comment: Where is you popViewController statement?

Comment: disconnect datasource and delegate for UITableview and then try... your logic might be wrong for the rest...

Comment: @yunas i just use the simplest method for UITableView no more method,i think it's not logic problem.very strange.

Comment: just put [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; when you reach the bottom of tableview. Note: Animation need to restrict by NO instead of YES

Comment: @wesley is right, if i set the animation NO,won't crash ,but i need the animation，do you have any good suggestion?

Comment: then after end the animation, call separate method for popViewController using performSelector with delay

Comment: So the problem is,tableview try to access scrollViewDidScroll delegate method during the time of animating viewController. so after reaching scroll at bottom, set datasource and delegate as Nil before popViewController.

Comment: @wesley yeah,u r right,i have already solve the problem ,thank u all the same.

Comment: So make this as answer and with approved one if am deserved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is,tableview try to access `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method during the time of animating viewController. so after reaching scroll at bottom, set `datasource` and `delegate` as Nil before popViewController.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

ExampleviewController *example=[[ExampleviewController alloc]]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:example animated:YES];

check UIScrollView Delegate is declared are not